# ifstream читает и возвращает пустую строку из файла

Tags: c++, файлы, filestream

Доброго времени суток.

У меня в папке лежат несколько файлов: **main.cpp**, **input.txt**.
В файле main.cpp я читаю строку из файла, разделяю строку по точкам (нахожу предложения), затем с помощью одной функции проверяю самый первый символ каждого предложения на то, является ли он заглавным. Если нет, то меняю на оный.

Т.е это должно выглядеть так:

```
Current input: I have no choice. glory to mankind. Glory. to. Mankind.
After: I have no choice. Glory to mankind. Glory. To. Mankind.
```

Ну и понятное дело, что в input.txt у меня хранится:

```
I have no choice. glory to mankind. Glory. to. Mankind.
```

Итак, я писал этот проект с помощью CLion IDE. Всё работало.
Но потом я решил в отдельной папке сделать тоже самое и скомпилировать в консоли, правда я столкнулся с проблемой, что **у меня возвращается пустая строка из файла**.

Вот main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>



using namespace std;

string getResult(vector<string> val) {
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < val.size(); i++) {
        // Iteration
        string current = val[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < current.size(); j++) {
            if (current[j] != ' ') {
                // If first word is uppercase
                if (flag && isupper(current[j]) == 0) {
                    current[j] = toupper(current[j]);
                    val[i] = current;
                }
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        flag = true;
    }

    string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < val.size(); i++)
        result += val[i] + ".";

    return result;
}



int main() {
    ifstream file("input.txt");
    string str;
    string file_contents;

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Some problems with file...";
        return -1;
    }



    while (getline(file, str)) {
        file_contents += str;
        file_contents.push_back('\n');
    }

    vector<string> array;

    // split
    istringstream is(str);
    string s;
    while (std::getline(is, s, '.'))
        array.push_back(s);

    cout <<"Current input: "<< str << endl;

    string result = getResult(array);

    cout << "After: " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Собираю проект в консоли: `g++ -o prog main.cpp`. Запускаю: `./prog`
Получаю это

```
Current input: 
After:
```

Никак не могу понять, в чём дело и что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (getline(file, str)) {
    file_contents += str;
    file_contents.push_back('\n');
}
```

После этого str имеет значение последней строки вашего файла. Что у вас в последней строке, думаю вы сами догадались (ничего).

```
istringstream is(str);  // а str пустая строка
string s;
while (std::getline(is, s, '.')) // а в is ничего нет
    array.push_back(s);
```

Думаю  вам лучше убрать эти строчи из кода и сразу  заносить все в вектор:

```
int main() {
ifstream file("input.txt");
string str;
string file_contents;
if (!file.is_open()) {
    cout << "Some problems with file...";
    return -1;
}
vector<string> array;
while (getline(file, str, '.'))  {
    array.push_back(str);
    file_contents += str;
    file_contents += '.';
}

cout <<"Current input: "<< file_contents << endl;
string result = getResult(array);
cout << "After: " << result << endl;
return 0;
}
```

P.S. это тривиальная задача, и ее можно решить проще.

Comment: Спасибо.

Только у Вас небольшая опечатка
```cout <<"Current input: "<< file_contents; << endl;```
Но это совсем не имеет значения.

Comment: Пожалуйста,  а  опечатка  быпа, я исправил. И вам спасибо за  информацию